# getMetadata("dbg") returns NULL despite producing IR with "clang -g -S -emit-llvm"

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm trying to get line information for an instruction.
I have

```
const CallInst* callInst = dyn_cast<const CallInst>(&*I);
MDNode *N = callInst->getMetadata("dbg");
```

N is evidently NULL, but I have compiled the input IR with "clang -g -S -emit-llvm" 
Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your instruction doesn't correspond to any statement of the source program and thus has no debug metadata.

For example it was generated by one or another optimization as passing `-emit-llvm` not only emits llvm, but applies bundle of optimizations to your program first.

To exclude optimizations influence and to see the pure code just after the front-end do `clang -g -S -emit-llvm -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns` and ensure your instruction has the metadata required.